# Access denied exception during File deletion in windows8 from different admin user

Tags: visual-c++, uac, permission-denied

In my application, one configuration file has been generated from a particular admin user account. Now from a different admin user account, my application is trying to delete the old configuration and then create new one, but was not able to delete the old configuration file, my application throws access denied exception.

In my vc++ project settings Linker->manifest, I changed the UACExecutionLevel from RunAsAdministrator to AsInvoker to meet some other requirements but ultimately end up with this critical issue. Can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: i assume the file is still open by the first user; and that is the source of the access denied error.